# LRO unicode control character in Winform TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, textbox

I am experiencing a problem with the WinForm TextBox displaying unicode control characters. 
A string is constructed containing some right to left characters (Hebrew for example) but the string begins with a LRO (left to right override). This string is then assigned to a TextBox' Text property, for example:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "\u202Dדוד";
```

This displays fine and even ensures that the left to right semantics are used; however, the TextBox counts the LRO as a character and thus the cursor can be moved through it. Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Why you don't delete \u202D, this is exist for what?

Comment: \u202D is the LRO, forcing left to right for the following points

Comment: I tested it but no different have seen.